# How to set timer for the follwing scroll to top function

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have the following simple `scrollTop()` function obtained from w3schools. The issue i have is setting the time for scrolling. Different people gave different methods and everyone removed one or all lines from the following code. I'm waiting for a function which can be added to set the scrolling speed and no other text is to be removed. Here's the codepen work https://codepen.io/vkdatta27/pen/zYqQbmM

```js
var mybutton = document.getElementById("myBtn");

window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction()
};

function scrollFunction() {
  if (document.body.scrollTop > 20 || document.documentElement.scrollTop > 20) {
    mybutton.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    mybutton.style.display = "none";
  }
}

// When the user clicks on the button, scroll to the top of the document
function topFunction() {
  document.body.scrollTop = 0;
  document.documentElement.scrollTop = 0;
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}
#myBtn {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  z-index: 99;
  font-size: 18px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 15px;
  border-radius: 4px;
}
#myBtn:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth
}
```

```html
<button onclick="topFunction()" id="myBtn" title="Go to top">Top</button>
<div style="background-color:black;color:white;padding:30px">Scroll Down</div>
<div style="background-color:lightgrey;padding:30px 30px 2500px">This example demonstrates how to create a "scroll to top" button that becomes visible
  <strong>when the user starts to scroll the page</strong></div>
```

Comment: add example in codepen.io?

Comment: when I ran your code I didn't see a "Top" button appear

Comment: @dwosk, now check it.

Comment: Fixed it - you need to move the `<button>...</button>` to the top of the file. Otherwise, `myButton` is null since it hasn't been created yet.

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're looking for - have you looked at `window.scrollTo()`? For example: ```window.scrollTo({
    top: 0,
    behavior: "smooth"
});```

Comment: @dwosk, that's not the issue. I didn't properly indent code here at stackoverflow which you thought was the actual issue. The real thing is, i need `duration` like thing which can control scroll time.

Comment: @dwosk, that's not the issue. I didn't properly indent code here at stackoverflow which you thought was the actual issue. The real thing is, i need `duration` like thing which can control scroll time.

Comment: @dwosk, `Behaviour : smooth ` is a near term. But, i have already added it (see codepen). I want a more smoother effect. I want the scroll top function to happen in 2 seconds which will be more smoother

Comment: @DarlanD., i added a codepen work.

Comment: If got it, please accept this answer if it solved your problem. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the function `topFunction` of your `onclick="topFunction()"` this no good pratic, and add event listener to click button calling function to exec this code:

```
mybutton.addEventListener("click", scrollTime);

async function scrollTime() {
    var time = 5; //seconds
    var y = document.documentElement.scrollTop; //get y position of scroll
    var duration = y/time; //calcule duration steps 
    while(y>0)
    {
        y = y-duration; //subtract by duration
        window.scrollTo({top: y, behavior: 'smooth'}); //move to position y
        await new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, 1000)); //await function with 1000 ms by steps
    }
}
```

Comment: Yah,. Got it, Thanks for answer